# Assisted by friendship, on friendship, or ...?

Tags: legal-terms

let us say an attorney who is also a close friend of mine assist me just thanks to our friendship, **without charging any fee**. Question is, is there a way to refer to such kind of situation? Would you use something like assisted *on a friendly basis*, or *in friendship*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard the Latin expression *pro bono* being used when a lawyer agrees to work at a reduced fee, or even without charging any fee.

As far as I know, it is used both when the client is a friend or relative and when the client cannot afford to pay the fee.

Comment: Is there a way of saying to avoid confusion between those two cases (friend, unable to afford)?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Specifically because you said "on a friendly base", in American English, that phrase would be "on a friendly basis". You could also say, "as a favor to a friend."